# N записей длиной k бит каждая

Tags: c++

Начиная с адреса А в памяти МК находятся N записей длиной k бит каждая. Записи выровнены по границе слова. Написать функции для чтения/записи отдельных бит для любой записи из данного набора.

1-слово = 4-байта = 32 бита
Вопрос вот в чём как сделать длину записи например не стандартно 32, а допустим 33 бита или 37 бит?
и какие для этого использовать операции?

У меня вот что получилось, но это не совсем правильно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>
//extern char tim(char s9[100], int OldSize, int NewSize);
extern void _WRITE_MASK1();
extern void _WRITE_MASK2();
extern void _WRITE_BIT(long *j, int num_z, int num_byte, int num_bite, int _vol);
extern int _READ_BIT(long *j, int num_z, int num_byte, int num_bite);
#define N 1 // Ввод кол-ва записей по 4 байта.
int main() {
    int K=32;
    // Ввод кол-ва битов в каждой записи( от 1 до 32 )
    int Z=K-1;
    if((K<1)||(K>32)) {
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned long mass [N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) // формирование битов длиной К. {
        if(Z<2)
        mass[i]=pow(2,Z);
        if ((Z>=3)&(Z<10))
        mass[i]=pow(2,Z)+pow(2,Z-1)+pow(2,Z-2)+1;
        if ((Z>=10)&(Z<20))
        mass[i]=pow(2,Z)+pow(2,Z-2)+pow(2,Z-4)+pow(2,Z-6)+pow(2,Z-8)+i;
        if ((Z>=20)&(Z<32))
        mass[i]=pow(2,Z)+pow(2,Z-4)+pow(2,Z-8)+pow(2,Z-12)+pow(2,Z-16)+i;
    }
    _WRITE_MASK1();
    _WRITE_MASK2();
    int rtf =1;
    // 0 или 1
    int bit=1;
    // от 0 до 7
    int byte=3;
    ;
    // от 0 до 3
    int zap=4;
    // от 0 до кол-ва записей -1
    int k=(sizeof(mass))/sizeof(mass[0]);
    // определение кол-ва элементов
    if(((bit>7)||(bit<0)||(byte>3)||(byte<0)||(zap<0)||(zap>k-1))||((rtf!=0)&(rtf!=1))) {
        return 0;
    }
    _WRITE_BIT(&mass[0],zap,byte,bit,rtf);
    //zap от 0 до размера массива-1; byte от 0 до 4, бит от 0 до 7. Устанавливаем бит в памяти равный rtf
    int bitRead=1;
    // от 0 до 7
    int byteRead=3;
    // от 0 до 3
    int zapRead=4;
    // от 0 до кол-ва записей -1
    if((bitRead>7)||(bitRead<0)||(byteRead>3)||(byteRead<0)||(za pRead<0)||(zapRead>k-1)) {
        return 0;
    }
    int b = _READ_BIT(&mass[0],zapRead,byteRead,bitRead);
    int c=10;
}
```

Comment: @Twixs, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Twixs, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа. @Twixs, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно "добивать" конец записи до длинны слова. В вашем случае (C-стиль) проще всего работать со структурами, где можно заранее определить выравнивание.
Допустим, есть такие данные:

```
typedef struct tagRecord
{
    float data1;        // word (4 байта)
    double data2;       // double word (8 байт)
    int data3;          // word (4 байта)
    unsigned char data4; // 1 байт    
} Record;

// sizeof(Record) == 17,
//нужно "добить" размер до кратности размеру слова (4), т.е. до 20.

// Напишем обертку с необходимым выравниванием
typedef struct tagAlignedWrapper
{
    Record data; 
    char align[3];
} AlignedWrapper;
```

Крайние 3 байта можно просто игнорировать (не заполнять и не обрабатывать в функциях), но они автоматически будут выравнивать нашу структурку.

Это полезно для разношерстных данных. В вашем случае, **33 бита** будут представлены как:

```
typedef struct tagRecord
{
    char data[5]; // 7 бит в конце игнорируем
    char align[3];
} Record_33bit_aligned;
```

А **37 бит**, как ни странно, точно так же =)

```
typedef struct tagRecord
{
    char data[5]; // 3 бита в конце игнорируем
    char align[3];
} Record_37bit_aligned;
```